# maven pom.xml sensitive information and VCS

Tags: java, maven

I am developing one java app and I made pom.xml with database URL I am using:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>development</id>
        <properties>
            <db.url>jdbc:mysql://project.******.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306</db.url>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>validation</id>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Problem is I am using version control and I would not want to submit my specific configuration. What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the information in your personal `settings.xml`.

edit: And you should use encryption to save your credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Put this type of configuration outside of your pom file. There is no one right answer here... just use a personal settings or properties file or something to that effect. Then just omit that file from version control.

Answer (score 0):

in user home folder /.m2/settings.xml I have put this, works nice. Thanks!

```
<settings>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>development</id>
        <properties>
            <db.url>jdbc:mysql://project.******.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306</db.url>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>validation</id>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<settings>
```